# Creating four separate weeks for each calendar month in R

Tags: r, time, sequence

I have a weekly data set which roughly covers 11 years. The problem is that not every week begins on the 1st of the month, and not every week ends on the 7th of the month.

I tried to create a sequence for 1 month in weeks to see the corresponding dates, however the month of January (which is 31 days) ends on the 29th:

```
seq(as.Date("2004-01-01"), as.Date("2004-01-31"), 'weeks')
[1] "2004-01-01" "2004-01-08" "2004-01-15" "2004-01-22" "2004-01-29"
```

I need to create a sequence of weekly dates whereby each week of each month begins on the 1st and ends on either the 28th (for Feb), 30 or 31 (for others). Is this even possible? 
Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, but only months with 30-31 days.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question makes little sense in any traditional conceptualisation of what a week is.

Comment: @thelatemail. In order to map weekly time series data onto monthly data, there needs to be a consistent number of weeks for each calendar month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
begin <- seq(as.Date('2004-01-01'), as.Date('2014-02-01'), by='1 month')
end <- begin-1
lst <- split(v1, list(month(v1),year(v1)), drop=TRUE)
res <- unsplit(Map(function(x,y,z) {
      x[c(1, length(x))] <- c(y,z)
      x}, 
   lst, begin[-length(begin)], end[-1L]), list(month(v1), year(v1)))
head(res)
#[1] "2004-01-01" "2004-01-08" "2004-01-15" "2004-01-22" "2004-01-31"
#[6] "2004-02-01"
tail(res)
#[1] "2013-12-31" "2014-01-01" "2014-01-09" "2014-01-16" "2014-01-23"
#[6] "2014-01-31"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- seq(as.Date("2004-01-01"), as.Date('2014-01-31'), 'week')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your solution but the result is the same as what I had before.

Comment: @SAMIRSULTANI If you look at the end of January is `2004-01-31`, for February it is `2004-02-29`.  It is different from what you showed and it is as per your request

Comment: Oh yeah! thanks for that
I do however need it to go from the "2004-01-01" to "2014-01-31"

Comment: for around 132 months (11 years)

Comment: @SAMIRSULTANI Sorry didn't catch the `2014`.  In that case change the `begin` accordingly.

Comment: For the length right?
Gives me an warning message, however only the same sequence is spat out:

Warning message:
In mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) :
  longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter

Comment: Still get the same warning and length i.e. 22. I will rerun it again in case