# Generate a sequence of the same weeks every month in R

Tags: r, date, seq, as.date

I'm trying to generate a sequence of weeks which repeat itself for every month.

I've created the sequence for one month obviously, but I'd like that sequence to be the same for every month also.

```
sequence2 <- format(seq(as.Date("2004-01-01"), as.Date("2004-01-23"), by =    "week"), "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Which gives me:

```
sequence2
[1] "2004-01-01" "2004-01-08" "2004-01-15" "2004-01-22"
```

I want something like this:

```
"2004-01-01" "2004-01-08" "2004-01-15" "2004-01-22"
"2004-02-01" "2004-02-08" "2004-02-15" "2004-02-22"
.
.
.
```

The sequence should go up to 2014

Any assistance would be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating four separate weeks for each calendar month in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31238654/creating-four-separate-weeks-for-each-calendar-month-in-r)

Comment: Good luck dealing with leap years :-)

Comment: @SAMIR SULTANI, how is your request different than what you previous asked (as Pascal linked to above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create a vector of 'Dates' sequence ('v1'), `split` the vector based on `month` and `year`.  Use `lapply` to loop over the list and remove the day part and `paste` with the day from the first four observations (extracted using `substr`).

```
 library(lubridate)
 v1 <- seq(as.Date("2004-01-01"), as.Date("2014-01-23"), by = "week")
 lst <- split(v1, list(month(v1), year(v1)), drop=TRUE)
 days <- substr(v1[1:4],9,10)
 v2 <- unlist(lapply(lst, function(x) {
     sprintf('%s%s', substr(x[1:4], 1,8), days)}), use.names=FALSE)
 v2[1:8]
 #[1] "2004-01-01" "2004-01-08" "2004-01-15" "2004-01-22" "2004-02-01"
 #[6] "2004-02-08" "2004-02-15" "2004-02-22"
 tail(v2,8)
 #[1] "2013-12-01" "2013-12-08" "2013-12-15" "2013-12-22" "2014-01-01"
 #[6] "2014-01-08" "2014-01-15" "2014-01-22"
```

Or another option would be

```
 v1 <- seq(as.Date('2004-01-01'), length.out=4, by = 'week')
 len <- 4*12*10  + 4
 v2 <- rep(v1, len/4)
 v3 <- do.call(paste, c(d1[do.call(order, d1),][1:484,-3], sep="-"))
 res <- paste0(v3, sub('^\\d+-\\d+', '', v2))
 head(res,8)
 #[1] "2004-01-01" "2004-01-08" "2004-01-15" "2004-01-22" "2004-02-01"
 #[6] "2004-02-08" "2004-02-15" "2004-02-22"
 tail(res,8)
 #[1] "2013-12-01" "2013-12-08" "2013-12-15" "2013-12-22" "2014-01-01"
 #[6] "2014-01-08" "2014-01-15" "2014-01-22"
```

Comment: For some reason i get the following error:
Error in split.default(unclass(x), f, drop = drop) : 
  could not find function "month"

Comment: @SAMIRSULTANI Sorry, I loaded the package `data.table` It is also in `lubridate`.  But, you can extract the month with `format(v1, '%m')` and year with `format(v1, '%Y')`

Comment: Yeah that seems to do the trick...Cheers. 
So essentially, the initial sequence was split into months and years to identify the pattern yes?

Comment: @SAMIRSULTANI  Yes, I replicated the initial sequence and changed the Year and month

Comment: Ok, so regarding the first option above, in the "days" line of code, where "days <- substr(x[1:4], 9, 10)" - what does the 9, 10 stand for?

Comment: @SAMIRSULTANI  It is extracting the characters from the 9 to 10 th position.  In `?substr`, the arguments are `substr(x, start, stop)` , `start` is the start position

Answer (score 0):

The library 'timeDate' might be useful. It has a function 'timeCalendar':

```
library(timeDate)

t <- matrix(NA,0,4)

for ( year in 2001:2004 )
{
  for ( month in 1:12 )
  {
    t <- rbind(t,rep(NA,4))

    for ( i in 0:3 )
    {
      t[nrow(t),i+1] <- as.character(timeCalendar( y = year,
                                                   m = month,
                                                   d = 7*i+1) )
    }
  }
}
```